# need solution with ngfor

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

```
//appcomponent.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  heroes=[{name:"superman"},{name:"heman"}];
}
//app.component.html

<ul><li *ngfor="let hero of heroes">{{hero.name}}</li></ul>
```

This code is not works and gives me blank output. if you have solution for this.pls let me know

Comment: `*ngFor` instead of `*ngfor`?

Comment: *ngFor not *ngfor

Comment: Thanks picci ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have done one small syntactical mistake with `*ngfor`
It follows camel casing where f must be in captial case.

**Correct code is attached below:**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
    {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```